# ngrx - use @output or interact with store directly

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

What is better good practice ?!
Because ngrx give us the sore, we can listen for state and we can dispatch action from any component.

So I write some simple todos list application:

Container: TodosListComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todos-list',
  template: `
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let todo of list">
                <todo [todo]="todo"></todo>
            </li>
        </ul>
  `,
})
export class TodosListComponent implements OnInit {
  public list;
  constructor(private store: Store<any>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = this.store.select('todos','list');  
  }

}
```

Child: Todo Compnent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todo',
  template: `
    <span>{{ todo.content}}</span>
    <span (click)="delete(todo)"> X </span>
  `,
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() todo: Todo;
  constructor(
      private store: Store<any>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  delete(todo) {
      this.store.dispatch({type: 'DELETE_TODO', payload: todo});
  }
}
```

So in this way we listen for list(state) on TodosListComponent
then we can change the list from any component, in this case we delete todo from todo component the list will update auto by the store.

But other way is use @Output (event emitter) and then dispatch the action from the container?

My question is which way is better and why?

I think the first is better because if we have more complex example like data-grid element that listen for Results(state), we can change the result(state) from other components without complex event emitter

I fill the use of `@Output` is not needed because store give us the ability to listen and dispatch action every where.

But what is better, and why? :)

**I don't need code review because i ask about the data flow not about this app code(it's example).**

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think using `ngrx` to build an application is better way to create an application.

- In ngrx, you have a single source of data. Your data will always be updated in the store. So all the components will have updated data.
- Your child components can directly access the data from the store. They don't have to depend on the parent components for the data.
- If you use @Output, you would need to pass the properties from parent to the child components. If you want to add additional data you would need to update the entire code from parent to the child components.

Comment: So you think is better to dispatch action from child component?

Comment: Yes I think it's better to dispatch action from child components. It's my personal view, don't know the statistics. But I find it easier as you don't have to repeat code. `Components tells what it wants to do (action). Reducers update the store. And component get's the updated data.`. For me this flow works better for applications as it reduces complexity. For smaller application, may  be doing so many things for small small functionality may be hectic, but I think in bigger application using this approach provides better flexibility

Comment: i think it true, in my view we have smart and dumb component but we can split to small smart component, not big containers

Comment: Yes, because initially the components might be dumb, but as your application grows, you might need to pass more data. Now you have two choices either to create more properties in your parent component or create one more smart component to handle the situation. But in case of ngrx, as your child components have less dependency upon their parent components, you can easily manipulate data to handle new requirements.

Comment: I agree with @daniel hoppe alvarez, this should not be the answer. dumb components should stay dumb and only relay interaction. having a single source of truth does not change that system.

Comment: There are two different things - dumb/smart components & parent/child relationship. Dumb components should be used for displaying UI. They should get data from the smart components. My answer doesn't disputes that. In react without @ngrx you need to pass data from the parent to the child components (Both are smart components with their own dumb components to display UI). Ngrx is helping smart components to access data from the "single data source" instead of depending on their parent components as the level of hierarchy can be very large and keeping track of data required becomes difficult.

Answer (score 4):

In ngRx you have smart (container) and dumb (child) components. So in your case the List Component is the Smart Component because it has to subscribe to the todo Items from the state. The Todo Component would be a good example for a dumb component. It is a child from the listcomponent an does not have to be aware of the existence of the ngStore.

Why would you do this? Its a way to reduce a components complexity. If you have large applications it can become hard to track all the Components who are aware of the store.

For more detailed information:

[Smart Dumb Components explained with Code](https://hongbo-miao.gitbooks.io/angular2-server/content/part2/smart-and-dumb-component.html)

[A comprehensive introduction to ngRx](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510)

Comment: in this example this is small applcation, but if we build dashboard application, and we have data-grid so in container we listen the store.
but not we have new future in header , filter the time range of the results in the grid, so how we can dispatch action to change data from the header? is dumb component

Comment: exactly this is why it gets really hard to refactor your code if every component injects the store and dispatches actions.

Comment: in this example this is small applcation, but if we build dashboard application, and we have data-grid so in container we listen the store.
but now we need add a new future in header , filter the time range of the results in the grid, so how we can dispatch action to change data from the header? is dumb component

Comment: Your @inputs can except async values. So you would use Smart and Dumb Components and the dump Components get async inputs so if you emit an action the new Value gets emitted from the Parent Component to the Child Component

Comment: you maybe don't understand me, it true in this small example we have small application, but if are application is become large, think the smart component need to take care for all emitter from dumb component!, if we have 30 dumb component smart component need to handle 30 functions!

Comment: Well you are right I do not fully understand your point of view. But the problem you are addressing is about the interaction of smart and dumb components in the ngrx / redux pattern. It does not change in bigger or smaller applictions. So if you read the articles you can choose on your own in in your usecase EventEmitter are needed or not.

Comment: There is one other benefit of using dumb Components as your presentation component. You can make use of ChangeDetection.Onpush which can drastically enhance your componets performance

Comment: i accept that we need dumb component and use input with async pipe for Onpush Detection!, but i think smart component is not containers, for example i give large application: dashboard of football live score. the core component is container of header,sidenav, and router-outlet. the route is now 'overview' in router-outlet.
we have overviweContainer to show live score from api
we get data from store and use grid-component(use async),from header we can change the favorite team so we change the api call, so in your view header is dumb component? header can't dispatch action?